# Retrieving comments from deactivated Facebook account

Tags: facebook, export

Is there any way to retrieved comments from deactivated Facebook account?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do anything with deactivated account. First you have to reactivate it and then do whatever you want to do, later you can again deactivate.